# How to solve ERROR: must be member of role "postgres"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am very new to postgres. One of my project is using an RDS postgres instance, the application team created a user and use that user to create the database.

I am trying to grant default privilege to the default postgres user to this application database by running the command below but I am getting an error message.

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
FOR USER postgres
IN SCHEMA public
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO postgres;
```

Error message

```
ERROR:  must be member of role "postgres"
SQL state: 42501
```

Please advise how I can grant default privilege to postgres user for the database.

Comment: issue is not reproducible in PG 11.4, can you share the PG version.

Answer (score 2):

You must connect as a superuser to run this command.

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood my case earlier. Apparently, postgres user was the owner of the database not the app user. So I logged in as postgres and executed the command and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you did a pgdump to export the database, and then were getting this error on trying to import it. Use `-O` when creating the pgdump - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood my case earlier. Apparently, postgres user was the owner of the database not the app user. So I logged in as postgres and executed the command and it works.